setting figure size in Rmd file
I was playing around with Rmd code chunk settings.
I wanted to have a code chunk inside my Rmd file that set a figure size for a portion of my codes (that is why I don't put it in YAML header).
I do not knit the file, just looking at the inline image previews
```{r }
# set image dimensions
fig.width=5
fig.hight=5
units="in"
```

and then to apply it I want smth like this
```{r fig.height=fig.hight, fig.width=fig.width, units=units}
plot(pressure)
```

but this does not produce desired outcome, while specifying numbers directly inside the code works:
```{r fig.height=5, fig.width=5, units=units}
    plot(pressure)
```


I just wonder why

I can't reproduce the issue. I just created a new Rmd document. In the first chunk I put your fig.width and fig.hight definitions. The 2nd chunk was plot(pressure) with now options set. The 3rd chunk used your {r fig.height=fig.hight, fig.width=fig.width, units=units} with plot(pressure) again.  Knit to HTML, the first plot is normal sized, the second plot is huge. Maybe you could post code for a complete minimal example - the whole Rmd?

Make extra sure you don't have typos. Even in your question, you use hight instead of height. In the question you show it consistently in a way that should work: the chunk option is spelled correctly height and your own variable is misspelled consistently hight. But if you misspell a chunk option it will be silently ignored.

I am not knitting, just running the rmd chunks: and my images are not displayed in the same manner , I attached the image to illustrate my point

Interesting. The "not knitting, just looking at the the inline image previews" is a very important clarification - please edit it into your question. Those inline image previews are an RStudio feature--you might have better luck posting in an RStudio section of the Posit community forums. It may just be a bug/feature request for RStudio.
